# How can I improve one of my questions?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, quality-improvement

For example my question: [Dynamic hierarchical composite delegation in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44482123) has many flaws including:

- Too long
- Clumsy structure
- Even more poorly written the first time I posted it, so many who might have been interested have written it off.

At this point:

- Should I delete the original question and split it up?
- Try to find someone to help me reword it?
- Ask individual questions on meta about specific aspects of the posting I want to improve? For example, *I wanted to keep the code short so it was easy to see the whole function on one screen. Should I instead add comments and spacing?*

*Update:*
I added comments and whitespace to clarify the decorator code, and I eliminated all except one question. How can I further improve my posting: ([How can I reduce the recusion in dynamic hierarchical composite delegation in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44482123))

Comment: Ask only *one* question.  At SO *and* meta.  Do not force an anybody to only agree with your preselected correct answers.

Comment: When you get enough rep (?) you can visit the appropriate chat (like http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python) and ask for help.

Comment: For one, the "update" section with any kind of reference to how the question previously was needs to disappear. Its just confusing. Your question needs to ask a question and not read like a support request with a history of changes.